# case statement with in group by clause or partition by

Tags: sql

```
Customer   Decision      req_date       salary
   A       Approved     2017-06-13       1000
   A       Approved     2017-06-13       1000
   A       Pending      2017-06-13       500
   B       Pending      2017-10-23       800     
   B       final_stage  2017-10-20       400
   B       final_stage  2017-03-19       400
```

For a given customer ID,

case 1:If the decision is Approved,then retain all the approved records for that customer and drop others.

Case 2: If the customer doesn't have any Approved decision then ,retain  the records of particular customer based on latest "req_date" and records within 5 days of this most recent "req_date" and pick the record based on the lowest salary

```
Customer   Decision      req_date       salary  
   A       Approved     2017-06-13       1000
   A       Approved     2017-05-13       1000
   B       final_stage  2017-10-20       400
```

Comment: the output doesn't follow the explanation, for customer B.

Comment: @VamsiPrabhala : I believe it follows.Customer B doesn't have any approved decision ,so at step 1: we have 3 records for Customer B. At step 2 : we select the records based on the latest req_date and records within 5 days of this most recent "req_date".So at the end of step 2 ,we have 2 records for customer B. At step 3 ,we will pick one record out of those two based on the salary(ASC)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The rows have to be filtered in three steps. I would use a cte for calculating aggregates and a union of two queries for approved and not approved customers:

```
with cte as (
    select 
        customer, 
        bool_or(decision = 'Approved') as approved, 
        max(req_date) as last_date
    from my_table
    group by 1
)
select customer, decision, req_date, salary
from my_table
join cte using(customer)
where approved and decision = 'Approved'
union all (
    select distinct on(customer) customer, decision, req_date, salary
    from my_table
    join cte using(customer)
    where not approved 
    and req_date between last_date- '5day'::interval and last_date
    order by customer, salary
    )
```

[DbFiddle.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/a4163/2)

Comment: .It works ,Thanks.What if we want to apply case 2 logic  across unique departments .https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51832569/case-statement-within-group-by-clause-or-partition-clause