# case statement within group by clause or partition clause

Tags: sql

```
Customer   Decision      req_date      dept        salary
   A       Approved     2017-06-13      IT          1000
   A       Approved     2017-06-13      Sales       1000
   A       Pending      2017-06-13      IT          500
   B       Pending      2017-10-23      IT          800     
   B       final_stage  2017-10-20      Sales       400
   B       final_stage  2017-03-19      Sales       400
   B       final_stage  2017-03-20      Marketing   300
   B       pending      2017-10-20      Marketing   400
   B       Pending      2017-04-23      HR          800
```

For a given customer ID,

case 1:If the decision is Approved, then retain all the approved records for that customer and drop others.

Case 2: If the customer doesn't have any Approved decision then ,retain  the records of particular customer based on latest "req_date" and records within 5 days of this most recent "req_date" and pick the record based on the lowest salary across unique departments(dept).

```
Customer   Decision      req_date      dept        salary
   A       Approved     2017-06-13      IT          1000
   A       Approved     2017-06-13      Sales       1000
   B       Pending      2017-10-23      IT          800     
   B       final_stage  2017-10-20      Sales       400
   B       pending      2017-10-20      Marketing   400
```

Comment: How is this question different from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51831886/case-statement-with-in-group-by-clause-or-partition-by?

Comment: @GordonLinoff Thank you for sparing me 10-15 minutes of mental torture :-)

Comment: @ There is a change in the case 2 logic.Here we want to pick record across unique departments.

Comment: Why is this tagged for `postgresql` and `plsql`? PL/SQL is a part of the Oracle RDBMS and has nothing to do with Postgresql. ???

Comment: I removed the conflicting tags. Please only add a tag for the database that is relevant (the GUI tool used - PL/SQL Developer - is never relevant for such a question)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This logic is quite complicated.  The following calculates:

- The maximum `req_date` for each customer.
- The total number of approved for a customer.
- The sequence number by customer and department by salary.

These are then combined with logic to achiever what you want:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by customer, dept order by salary asc) as seqnum
      from (select t.*,
                   max(req_date) over (partition by customer) as max_req_date,
                   count(*) filter (where decision = 'Approved') over (partition by customer) as num_approved
            from t
           ) t
      where decision = 'Approved' or
            req_date >= max_req_date - interval '5 day'
     ) t
where decision = 'Approved' or
      (num_approved = 0 and seqnum = 1);
```

Comment: @gordon.I executed above query ,it shows me an error." Missing FROM-clause entry in subquery for table ". Did it worked for you ?

Comment: @user8545255 . . . All the subqueries have `from` clauses.